# How do I copy my MongoDB data files to a new server?

Tags: mongodb

I copied the two files in MongoDB's data folder, which is default in Windows machine (`C:\data\db`), but when I start the `mongo` shell and type `show dbs`, it will not show my database.

Steps I followed is as below.

1. copy the data files to `C:\data\db`
2. start the MongoDB server by `mongod --dbpath C:\data\db`
3. start the MongoDB shell by `mongo` command in command prompt
4. type `show dbs` command to list the databases

Why am I not able to see my databases?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server and shell are you using (output of `db.version()` and `version()` in the `mongo` shell)? What version of MongoDB are the files you are copying from? Are there any startup messages or warnings from `mongod`? It would be helpful if you can include some of the startup log information starting from the line including "[initandlisten] options .." through to "[initandlisten] waiting for connections ...".

Answer (score 0):

With MMAPv1 you could copy f.ex. local.* files to some new mongod instance and instance saw those. With wiredTiger, you cannot do it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

@Krishna, As you said `copy the data files to C:\data\db`. This is the location of directories for **MongoDB** database files.

As per MongoDB BOL [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

```
c:\data\db
c:\data\log
```

It's By default location of directories for your database and log files. This path is required during starting of `mongod server`.

If you want to see a new database in your `mongo shell`. Then you have to import dump (.json) file through `mongoimport`.

For example in my place the installation location of MongoDB is

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
```

In Bin Folder you shall see mongod as well as all mongo shell command. I am also attaching the screen shot , for your understanding

[image]

Now open the command prompt and set the location such as

```
 C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
```

Then import your (.json) dump files through `mongoimport` command like that

```
 C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongoimport --verbose filelocation of json file
```

**Note :-** Here (--verbose) will import all (.json) data files from your dump folder into MongoDB database.

For help of mongoimport you can type on that same windows like

```
 C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongoimport --help
```

After importing the (.json) database files . Go to your mongo shell command and type the command like

```
>show dbs
```

Then you can see all databases which you have import through `mongoimport` shell command.

For your further ref [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)